# What kinds of degrees are there in Europe that can be completed in 12-18 months?

Tags: degree, europe

I am just about to complete my Bachelor degree in Property Economics at the University of Technology, Sydney. I would like to study some more in Europe (France, Belgium, Holland or Switzerland) next year and preferably for 1 year to 18 months. I am thinking something in social science or (i know the complete other side of the spectrum) finance.

What options do i have for that time period - obviously most bachelor degrees are ruled out due to the time period.

Comment: This question is unclear. What do you mean by "types of degrees"?

Comment: what are other options other than master or bachelor degrees. As this is a short period to study for normally i was wondering if private colleges with shorter degrees are common or any other options i am unaware of. trying to figure out how i can study in Europe - in the location i want, for this time period and something that interests me

Comment: Not on your list of European countries, but masters degrees are only 1 year long in the UK. Depending on the program, you could do your dissertation work in another place (ie. switzerland). A friend of mine did exactly that, he took six months of courses for his MSc in London and then did his dissertation work at a swiss university.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any 1 year degrees in Europe - maybe somebody else can say something about that - but here is one alternative idea (not sure how feasible some of it is though, I only tried some of this from one European university to another):

- Go for a masters degree in economics. It's usually 2 years but

  - some universities do a 7 semester bachelor + 3 semester master, so if you can convince them that your bachelor is equivalent to theirs, you might be able to get into a 3 semester i.e. 18 month master.
  - if you have leftover credits from advanced classes in your bachelor or you can tolerate a heavier workload than most, you might be able to finish a regular 2 year master in 18 month. Ask lots of questions beforehand though, to make sure it's really possible - I almost did this and was right on course for the 18 month master but then I decided to take a side job and did the master in 2 years.
  - if you ask your current supervisor, he might know a professor in Europe, who will agree to supervise your master thesis together with him. Then you can do your coursework in Europe and get started on the master thesis there but finish it in Sydney.

As you've noticed, a bachelor is not feasible, because it usually takes 3 years.

Another thing to keep in mind - you didn't say anything about your language skills - is that bachelor level classes and any other entry level degrees you might find are usually taught in the local language. Even on the master level your choices might be limited (or it might not be possible at all) if you can only take classes taught in English.